# Issue related to choosing an object dynamically in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have Web-application in MVC framework with EntityFramework.

I have been stuck in the situation where i have to choose an object dynamically based on some value passed at run-time.

i have following code :

```
public void GetReportData(int repNo)
{
    MotionSoftEntities msEntity = new MotionSoftEntities();

    object reportData = null;
    if (repNo == 1)
    {
        reportData = msEntity.REP_MM_DEMOGRAPHIC.AsEnumerable(); 
    }
    else if (repNo == 2)
    {
       reportData = msEntity.REP_MM_BIRTHDAY.AsEnumerable(); 
    }
    else if (repNo == 3)
    {
        reportData = msEntity.REP_MM_ARCMEMBER.AsEnumerable(); 
    }
    else if (repNo == 4)
    {
        reportData = msEntity.Rep_MM_BadAddress.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

In above code, Each of the four entity table has MemberID Field Common.
now after getting reportData object result,i have to Join it with another Entity object table as something like follows:

```
 var resultData = from c in reportData
                   join p in PG_MEMBER on c.MemberID equals p.MemberID
```

but the above join code doesn't working as `reportData` is type of `Object` 
so is it possible to join with dynamic object ??

i have tried following:

```
private IEnumerable<T> FilterData<T>(object value) where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> obj = (IEnumerable<T>)value;

    var resultData = from c in obj.AsEnumerable()
                     join r in PG_MEMBER on c.Field<int>("MemberID") equals r.MemberID
                     select c;
}
```

but above code also not working..

how can i solve my problem ??.
Thanks

Comment: Can your different entities implement a common interface?  Then instead of `object` you can declare the variable as that interface type.  (Though I'm not 100% certain how that would work in query translation.)

Comment: each of four tables are Tables of EntityFramework, automatically generated. so there is no any common interface.

Comment: They're not generated as partial classes?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: yes they are generated as partial class.

Comment: @ Loetn  yes.. i need only memberID

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani: Try implementing the interfaces in partial class definitions then.

Comment: @David.. we are not allowed to change the classes.. pls suggest another way

Comment: I suspect you (or someone on your team) are misinterpreting that "requirement".  In any event, another user's answer below is a perfectly acceptable "other way", with some pretty good advice on starting simple and refactoring to patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On possible way would be to use `dynamic`. You need to change `reportData` to type `IEnumerable<object>` instead of `object`. (The join will be performed in memory)

```
IEnumerable<object> reportData;

var resultData = from c in reportData
                 join p in PG_MEMBER on ((dynamic)c).MemberID equals ((dynamic)p).MemberID
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to join a query that could return *any one of four different types* and assume they all work because they share a common property by name. You could go down the path of dynamic, interfaces, reflection, etc. but they will make the code harder to understand and introduce risk of run-time errors.

I would break each report type into a separate method. Yes, you'll have some code duplication, but it will make the code easier to understand (and I suspect you'll have more divergent code between them that you think) and get you something that *works* sooner:

```
public void GetReport1Data()
{
    var reportData = msEntity.REP_MM_DEMOGRAPHIC.AsEnumerable(); 
    var resultData = from c in reportData
                   join p in PG_MEMBER on c.MemberID equals p.MemberID

    ... do other stuff

}

public void GetReport2Data()
{
    var reportData = msEntity.REP_MM_BIRTHDAY.AsEnumerable(); 
    var resultData = from c in reportData
                   join p in PG_MEMBER on c.MemberID equals p.MemberID

    ... do other stuff

}
```

.. etc.

Once you get it to *work* then you can focus on making it *better* by refactoring, changing design (if necessary), etc.  If your efforts to improve it become too complex, at least you have something that *works* to fall back on rather than getting in a rut trying to find the "perfect" design.